# Upload file using Spring boot and angular

Tags: spring-boot, angular8

i need to upload file using spring boot and angular
So this is the controller code which is well worked using Postman

```
 @PostMapping("/uploadFile")
 public ResponseEntity<String> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    String fileName = fileStorageService.storeFile(file);
    String message = "";
    String fileDownloadUri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()
            .path("/downloadFile/")
            .path(fileName)
            .toUriString();

    message = "You successfully uploaded " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!";
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(message);
}
```

but when i called the endPoint in angular that way

-Service code:

```
pushFileToStorage(file: File): Observable<HttpEvent<{}>> {
    const formdata: FormData = new FormData();
    formdata.append('file', file);
    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', this.indicatorUrl+'/uploadFile', formdata, {
    reportProgress: true,
    responseType: 'text' });
 return this.httpclient.request(req);}
```

-Component.ts code :

```
  title = 'File-Upload-Save';
  selectedFiles: FileList;
  currentFileUpload: File;
  progress: { percentage: number } = { percentage: 0 };
  selectedFile = null;
  changeImage = false;


change($event) {
    this.changeImage = true; }
changedImage(event) {
    this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];}
upload() {
    this.progress.percentage = 0;
    this.currentFileUpload = this.selectedFiles.item(0);
    this.indicatorservice.pushFileToStorage(this.currentFileUpload).subscribe(event => {
    if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
         this.progress.percentage = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
    } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
         alert('File Successfully Uploaded');
    }
    this.selectedFiles = undefined;
 }); }
selectFile(event) {
this.selectedFiles = event.target.files; }
```

-HTML code :

```
 <h1>Upload and Download File</h1>
<input type="file" id="customFile" (change)="selectFile($event)">
<button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!selectedFiles || admincheck || status" 
(click)="upload()">Save File</button>
```

This ERROR appeared

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/uploadFile' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

> POST http://localhost:8080/uploadFile net::ERR_FAILED

> ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://localhost:8080/uploadFile", ok: false, …}

> zone.js:3331 XHR failed loading: POST "http://localhost:8080/uploadFile".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the major issues which I can see in your code which you will come across, later on, You missed setting content type in your Angular code.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/">
```

CORS is web standard for adding security. You should read about it in detail. Adding @CrossOrigin annotation at your controller class should fix issue. This tutorial mention many ways to fix this issue
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors